# Ifelse statements for a dataframe in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am hoping that someone can help me figure out how to write an if-else statement to work on my dataset.  I have data on tree growth rates by year.  I need to calculate whether growth rates decreased by >50% from one year to the next.  I am having trouble applying an ifelse statement to calculate my final field.  I am relatively new to R, so my code is probably not very efficient, but here is an example of what I have so far:
For an example dataset,

```
test<-data.frame(year=c("1990","1991","1992","1993"),value=c(50,25,20,5))
  year value
1 1990    50
2 1991    25
3 1992    20
4 1993     5
```

I then calculate the difference between the current year and previous year's growth ("value"):

```
test[-1,"diff"]<-test[-1,"value"]-test[-nrow(test),"value"]
  year value diff
1 1990    50   NA
2 1991    25  -25
3 1992    20   -5
4 1993     5  -15
```

and then calculate what 50% of each years' growth would be:

```
test$chg<-test$value * 0.5
  year value diff  chg
1 1990    50   NA 25.0
2 1991    25  -25 12.5
3 1992    20   -5 10.0
4 1993     5  -15  2.5
```

I am then trying to use an ifelse statement to calculate a field "abrupt" that would be "1" when the decline from one year to the next is greater than 50%.  This is the code I am trying to use, but I'm not sure how to properly reference the "chg" field from the previous year, because I am getting an error (copied below):

```
test$abrupt<-ifelse(test$diff<0 && abs(test$diff)>=test[-nrow(test),"chg"],1,0)
Warning message:
In abs(test$diff) >= test[-nrow(test), "chg"] :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> test
  year value diff  chg abrupt
1 1990    50   NA 25.0     NA
2 1991    25  -25 12.5     NA
3 1992    20   -5 10.0     NA
4 1993     5  -15  2.5     NA
```

A test of a similar ifelse statement worked when I just assigned a few numbers, but I'm not sure how to get this to work in the context of a datframe.  Here is an example of it working on just a few values:

```
prevyear<-50
curryear<-25
chg<-prevyear*0.5
> chg
[1] 25
> diff<-curryear-prevyear
> diff
[1] -25
> abrupt<-ifelse(diff<0 && abs(diff)>= chg,1,0)
> abrupt
[1] 1
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to apply a similar ifelse statement to my dataframe I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you for any help you can provide.

thank you,
Katie

Comment: On an unrelated note, is there an alternative way to write this line of code from your question
`test[-1,"diff"]<-test[-1,"value"]-test[-nrow(test),"value"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change where you're putting `chg` so that it lines up with the `diff` you want to compare it to:

```
test$chg[2:nrow(test)] <- test$value[1:(nrow(test)-1)] * 0.5
```

Then, correct your logical operator like Blue Magister said:

```
test$abrupt<-ifelse(test$diff<0 & abs(test$diff)>=test$chg,1,0)
```

and you have your results:

```
  year value diff  chg abrupt
1 1990    50   NA   NA     NA
2 1991    25  -25 25.0      1
3 1992    20   -5 12.5      0
4 1993     5  -15 10.0      1
```

Also, you may find the function `diff` helpful: rather than doing this:

```
test[-1,"value"]-test[-nrow(test),"value"]
```

you can just do

```
diff(test$value)
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered my question.  I marked Jonathan's answer because this solved the problem beautifully, but thanks to Blu Magister for pointing out the error in my ifelse statment and to Arun for showing me a more efficient way of calculating the difference between values for two years.  Thanks again for the help everyone.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I am now trying to apply the code from Jonathan's answer to my real data.  There are some legitimate "NA" values in by real data so that the "abs" statement is not working in my final ifelse statement.  So, I try to use this code:

Answer (score 4):

It's throwing a warning because the two vectors compared `abs(test$diff) >= test[-nrow(test),"chg"]` have different lengths. Also, for *logical and*, you are using `&&` (which gives only one TRUE or FALSE) when you should be using `&` (which is vectorized: it operates elementwise over two vectors and returns a vector of the same length). Try this:

```
test$abrupt<-ifelse(test$diff<0 & abs(test$diff)>=test$chg,1,0)
```

Comment: This compares the wrong `diff` and `chg` unless `chg` is calculated differently (see my answer), but +1 for showing the source of the error.

Comment: I have a follow-up question:  I am trying to apply Jonathan's code to my real data.  I have legitimate "NA" values in my real data which is preventing the "abs" function in the final ifelse statement from running.  When I try to apply the statement to my real data, I get this error: Error in abs(test$diff) : 
  Non-numeric argument to mathematical function.   Does anyone have a suggestion for how to ignore the "NA" values when using the "abs" function in this statement?  I think I need to use na.omit, but am not sure where it would fit within that ifelse statement.  Thanks for any help! Katie

Comment: @user1913921 `abs(NA)` correctly returns `NA` for me. What is `class(test$diff)` and `mode(test$diff)`?